# telnet: "No environment-specified terminal type."

Tags: telnet

If I batch SSH this command:

```
echo close | /usr/bin/telnet IPADDRESS 657
```

Then I get this output:

```
No environment-specified terminal type.
```

but why? The OS FROM I'm SSHing is a Linux, and the OS where I'm SSHing TO is AIX.

Answer (score 3):

Because Telnet is designed to be an interactive tool to interact with a smart terminal. It doesn't receive the right terminal data (TERM environment variable etc) when fed from a pipe. Also, it performs negotiations with the remote host for terminal parameters, which may disturb the communications.

The right tool for application like yours - non-interactive TCP connections - is NetCat, `nc`.

Try

```
  echo close | /usr/bin/nc IPADDRESS 657
```

and use it for such applications from now on. You'll save yourself many headaches in the future - by avoiding some very hard to trace bugs originating from Telnet doing stuff "behind the scenes".

Comment: there is no netcat, are there other solutions? like a telnet like perl solution? :D Thanks

Comment: @gaskopeter: There are as many telnet clients as systems, or more. Read documentation of yours to see if it supports options to suppress terminal negotiations or assume dumb terminal. Although personally, I'd advise you to install netcat and learn its options. It can often save your skin, especially with its `-L`.

Comment: @gaskopeter As far as I know every linux distribution has a netcat package.

Comment: "SSHing TO is AIX"

Comment: @gaskopeter: And what machine is under "IPADDRESS" you try to telnet to?

Comment: I think that doesn't counts, Linux

Comment: Yep, makes it pretty clear. Unfortunately I have no clue what options AIX telnet client takes, nor what telnet alternatives are supported on that system.